# AssetManager$AssetInputStream.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: android, performance, crash, samsung-mobile

We see an stream of the following crashes, all on Android 4.3 Samsung Galaxy s3

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
       at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.close(AssetManager.java:559)
       at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.finalize(AssetManager.java:592)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Help anyone?

Comment: Are you using Crashlytics by an chance?

Comment: @plinehan i do. Is it connected?

Comment: That's my current theory.  It started happening in our app around March of last year after a Crashlytics update, and some Twitter employees confirmed that they saw similar crashes and ended up reverting the Crashlytics version.

I've updated to the latest version of Crashlytics and I'll see if it has any improvement on that crash, but it will be a few weeks before the release makes it out to the public.

Comment: I had a crash like this, and realized after checking the phone type that it was a Blackberry, not a true Android phone.

Comment: Anyone find any resolution?i hv also found issue in SM-G900I,5.0

Comment: We face similar problem since long. It might be linked to crashlytics. has anyone figured it out?

Comment: @CarlAnderson BlackBerry company has Android smartphones. Example: http://www.gsmarena.com/blackberry_priv-7587.php

Comment: @rishabhmhjn I have this issue without having Crashlytics. I got it recently via the Play Store, as they catch all crashes using their new feature that was recently added ("Vitals"). It's very similar to Crashlytics, though. Could be because Google bought them.

Comment: @androiddeveloper they didn't in 2015 when this question came up.

Comment: @CarlAnderson Who are "they" and what they "didn't" ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper why this isn't clear? My comment, that I wrote in May 2015, was that I only encountered this crash type on a BlackBerry phone. At that time BB didn't actually manufacture official Android phones, instead they used (broken) emulation to run Android apps on the BB OS, so this sort of crash wasn't worth fixing. You commented (tagging me!) with a BB phone that wasn't released until November(!) of 2015 that finally ran Android natively, as some sort of counterpoint? And so I tried to explain that they (BlackBerry) didn't have phones running native Android at the time of my comment

Comment: @CarlAnderson Oh ok.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you do read/write operation using StreamReader/StreamWriter classes, please make sure you are calling `ioStream.close()` inside first `try{}` block. Something like this:

```
    AssetManager AssetManager = mContext.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream is = AssetManager.open("sample.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Even If you have another `try{}` block under `catch/finally {}` block still it will throw above exception.

instead you can assign `ioStream = null` in `catch/finally {}` block.

```
catch (Exception ex) {
  // If ioStream object is outside the try block
  ioStream = null;
}
```